# GNU Make: Using the filter function in prerequisites

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to compile some C++ files and I absolutely have to put all object files in a separate build directory, but stored completely flat, i.e., without any further subdirectories. I know the common solution using VPATH, which goes something like this:

```
SOURCES = foo/one.cpp \
    foo/bar/two.cpp \
    foo/bar/sub/three.cpp

OBJDIR = obj

VPATH=$(dir $(SOURCES))

OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(notdir $(SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)))

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.cpp
    @echo Should compile: $(filter %/$*.cpp, $(SOURCES))
    @echo Compiling $<

all: $(OBJECTS)
```

This example pretty much works: I get three object files one.o, two.o, three.o in the 'obj' subdirectory (you can assume it just exists).

Now here's the catch when using VPATH: If there happens to be a file 'foo/three.cpp', then *this* will be compiled instead of the 'foo/bar/sub/three.cpp' which is named in the SOURCES variable. And no, I cannot rename either file; this name clash simply exists and I cannot do anything about that.

So my question is: How can I tell Make to *only* use '.cpp' files which appear in the SOURCES variable? I think the best solution would be to use that 'filter' statement in the target's prerequisite. I think this should be possible using secondary expansion, but I don't know what to do with the '%'. For example, I tried

```
 .SECONDEXPANSION:
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : $$(filter %/$$*.cpp, $(SOURCES))
```

but that doesn't work.

---

**UPDATE**: With the help of tripleee, I managed to get this working using the following:

```
define make-deps
$(OBJDIR)/$(notdir $(1:%.cpp=%.o)): $1
endef

$(foreach d, $(SOURCES), $(eval $(call make-deps,$d)))

%.o : 
    @echo Should compile $^ into $@
    @echo Compiling $^
```

Comment: Why do you need to put all `.o` files into one flat directory?

Comment: That's how the existing build works, and other tools working on those object files depend on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the easiest solution to your problem would be to get rid of `VPATH` and document each dependency explicitly. This can easily be obtained from your `SOURCES` definition; perhaps you want to define a function, but it really boils down to this:

```
obj/one.o: foo/one.cpp
obj/two.o: foo/bar/two.cpp
obj/three.o: foo/bar/sub/three.cpp
```

The actual rule can remain, only it should no longer contain the dependencies in-line, and you can skip the `obj/` subdirectory, because it's declared explicitly in each dependency:

```
%.o : # Dependencies declared above
    @echo Should compile $^ into $@
    @echo Compiling $^
```

I changed the rule to use `$^` instead of `$<` in case you ever have more than a single dependency.  This may be right or wrong for your circumstances; revert the change if it's not what you need.

In order to not need to maintain the dependencies by hand, you might want to generate `%.d` for each `%.cpp` file.  See [the GNU Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html).  (I tried to do this by using a `define`, but it seems you cannot declare dependencies with a `foreach` loop.)

In response to the question in the comment, this should not affect parallel builds in any way; it merely disambiguates the dependencies where your original Makefile was ambiguous when there were multiple biuld candidates with the same name in the `VPATH`.  There are no new dependencies and no new rules.

Comment: A separate rule for each source file instead of the pattern rule? But then I cannot do parallel builds, can I?

Comment: @pokita explicit dependencies like the above don't affect parallel builds. In other words, it doesn't matter how the dependency tree is built, once it has been built it can remake targets in parallel.

Comment: Those are not separate rules, anyway, just separate dependencies. If anything, a single rule to build everything at once is unparallelizable; separate, independent dependency chains can be built independently, i.e. also in parallel.

Comment: Updated the answer somewhat.

Comment: Thank you very much! Since I'm generating automatic dependencies during compilation with gcc, I did use your suggestion do use 'define' for generating these explicit dependencies, which works nicely.